# How to Take screenshot using Robot Framework in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm working on an automation project in java using selenium. When there is a failure, need to take a screenshot of web view. Used `TakesScreenshot` and it's working fine both in *chrome-driver* and in *phantomjs-driver*.

But this fails when an alert box is present. After some research, I understood that Selenium can't take a screenshot if alert is present. Alert must be handled first. And I can use `java.awt.Robot`, in such scenario, where the alert box is needed in my screenshot.

But `Robot` takes screenshot of my screen and won't get the web view, if using *phantomjs-driver* or if chrome is running minimized. But I need the screenshot with alert box (which represents the failure condition).

Is there any other solution for this issue?

Comment: is there any specific dependency which makes you run it in minimized window? becoz it is not minimized Robot should give you what is required.

Comment: included 'minimized' because, if I'm doing some other works in the same system, while the automation process is running in a browser which is minimized. Any way, if this will be using phantomjs, `Robot` wont give the necessary image right?

Comment: Robot screenshot is as good as hitting your prtscrn button on keyboard.. so if it captures everything visible on screen.. Just see if you time the activities so that the window is maximized just when the alert box comes up..

Comment: OK. That means, can't get screenshot, if using `phantomjs` driver? In that case, please suggest an alternate solution. I cant find any googling.

Comment: if it is web automation.. you can automate the web part using Selenium webdriver and the screenshot part could be easily done in Robot Class of java. By RobotFramework here you mean Robot class in Java or the python based RobotFramework?

Comment: Yes. It's a web automation using `selenium`, api for java. My requirement is to capture screenshot, including the alert box, when `phantomjs` is the webdriver. `TakesScreenshot` won't do that due to presence of alert box. As per my knowledge, `Robot` won't do that, because it's a process with no UI. I mean `java.awt.Robot`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134447/discussion-between-waman-and-ramanujan-r).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to capture the screen with alert then there is a way. Put your code portion for taking screenshot inside a try-catch block. If any alert found, it will throw an exception and in the catch block handle it.

Code snippet:

```
Alert alert = null;

    try {
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("screenshot.png"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        if(e.getMessage().contains("unexpected alert open:")){
            //before taking screenshot, you may wait for some moment to be properly visible
            try {
                 BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture((new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize())));

                     File file = new File("screenshot.jpg");
                     ImageIO.write(screencapture, "png", file);
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    alert.accept(); //or you can use dismiss();
```

**Note:**  For taking screenshot using robot your window must be visible.

Comment: " For taking screenshot using robot your window must be visible". If I'm using `phantomjs` webdriver. Robot won't help.